# Java - Callable contructor overwrites variable

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, callable

I am trying to make parallel calls with threads. For this I am using Callable interface because I need a parameter. The problem is that I make the threads with a parameter in a loop and the value passed is always overwritten so when it reaches **call()** method it always has the last passed value.

```
private HotelResponseDto getHotelsCall(HotelRequest request) {
    Set<Suggestion> suggestions = repository.findByHistoryId(request.getId());
    List<Callable<HotelWrapperDto>> calls = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(suggestions.size());

    for (Suggestion s : suggestions) {
        request.setCityCode(s.getName());
        calls.add(new MyCallable(request)); //beginning of the issue
    }

    List<Future<HotelWrapperDto>> results = null;

    try {
        results = executor.invokeAll(calls);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<HotelWrapperDto> wrappers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Future<HotelWrapperDto> f : Objects.requireNonNull(results)) {
        try {
            wrappers.add(f.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            log.error("Something didn't work.");
        }
    }

    HotelResponseDto response = new HotelResponseDto();
    response.setWrappers(wrappers);
    return response;
}
```

**And here is MyCallable class**

```
class MyCallable implements Callable<HotelWrapperDto> {

    private HotelRequest hotel;

    MyCallable(HotelRequest request) {
        hotel = request;
       //Here is the problem
       //Because I call this constructor in a loop,
       //hotel variable is always overwritten and in the end
       //I get the last result for every iteration 
    }

    @Override
    public HotelWrapperDto call() {
        HotelRequest hotelRequest = helper.createHotelRequest(hotel);
        HotelWrapperDto wrapper = hotelService.getHotels(hotelRequest);

        return wrapper;
    }
}
```

I have ridden other posts regarding threads with parameters but I did not find any solution.
How can I find a solution that will work for my case?
(I will clean code later)

Comment: I think the problem is that you have only one `request` object shared between all your `MyCallable` instances.

Comment: Yes, that solved it. Thank you!